# GROUP_CONCAT multiple where condition particular data

Tags: mysql, sql

> Query

```
(SELECT
    pid,
    visitdate,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tooth, ' - ', problem, ' - ', recomendation SEPARATOR ', <br>')
FROM tbl_finds_d) V
WHERE V.pid='1' AND V.visitdate = '16-03-2020'
```

> TABLE
>   Want to get WHERE pid=1 AND visitdate=16-03-2020

```
pid   visitdate   tooth   problem   recomendation
 1     16-03-2020   13     ASX        DFFF
 1     16-03-2020   12     JHJ        HJLP
 2     12-03-2020   14     JKB        IJLHJ
```

---

**UPDATE (copied from the comment)**

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM pendingtreatment A 
INNER JOIN tbl_finds_m B ON B.pid = '$pid' 
                        AND B.visitdate = '$visitdate' 
INNER JOIN treatmentadviced C ON C.pid = '$pid' 
                             AND C.visitdate = '$visitdate' 
INNER JOIN treatmentlist D ON D.pid = '$pid' 
                          AND D.visitdate = '$visitdate' 
INNER JOIN tbl_appointments E ON E.pid = '$pid' 
                             AND E.visitdate = '$visitdate' 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT pid, 
                    visitdate, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(tooth, ' - ', problem, ' - ', recomendation SEPARATOR ', <br>') 
             FROM tbl_finds_d V 
             WHERE V.pid='$pid' 
               AND V.visitdate = '$visitdate') F 
WHERE A.pid = '$pid' 
  AND A.visitdate = '$visitdate'
```

Comment: Remove excess parenthesis (before SELECT and after tablename).

Comment: Using INNER JOIN before it

Comment: Show FULL query text.

Comment: Is that date stored in a varchar?

Comment: Yes it's VARCHAR

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Please do not post the info in a comment - edit the question text.

Comment: While formatting your query you may see that: 1) no joinig condition for subquery joining (it is CROSS JOIN in such case) 2) no alias for the field in a subquery for to refer to it in outer query.

Comment: Additionally - when the record(s) matched the conditions are absent in at least one of the tables then this record will not be selected.